# Bluemix Java Liberty Web Project java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when loading third party jar

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

Im using IBM Bluemix's Java For Liberty to deploying a web app.

I was trying to get the system env and converted it to JSONObject

[image]

And I pretty sure Ive added the jar file to the classpath

[image]

However, after I ran the app(tried push to bluemix cloud and running locally in a liberty profile app server), it throws **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

[image]

please indicate how should I configure.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jars in the `dep-jar` folder do NOT get packaged with the final application binary(war). It is meant to be used during compilation only. If you want the jar to be included in the war (use during runtime), you need to include it in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

If you create and download the `Java DB Web Starter` boilerplate, you will see the right structure set up - `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/nosqljson.jar`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your jar's to the `dep-jar` folder and build the war file with the included `build.xml`.

Look for `classPathDir` in `build.xml`, it will look like the following.

```
<path id="classpathDir">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="dep-jar/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar"/>
    </path>
```

You will need to add each of your jar's to that block.  For example.

```
    <path id="classpathDir">
        <pathelement location="bin"/>
        <pathelement location="dep-jar/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="dep-jar/json-1.0.0.jar"/>
    </path>
```

Or you could do the following which would include all jar's in `dep-jar`.

```
<path id="classpathDir">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="dep-jar/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.1.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="dep-jar/" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks, But after I add those lines it still didnt work. What I did is after I modified, I 1. right click the project, 2.click the "export" button 3. save it as webStarterApp.war. then in cf i use command "cf push myapp"

Comment: The flow is a little wrong, right click `build.xml` and choose run as -> ant build.  That should do the trick.  Can you update your question with what you tried?

Comment: thanks Jeff, yes, jar files should be in the webinf/libs folder. Anyway i should use ant to build the project instead of using export, they are totally different, I tried unzip the two war file they have different structure.